# yarn EPERM (operation not permitted) on symlink on Azure App Service

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, yarnpkg

I have had a custom deployment process set up for a while that will build a dotnet core + React app directly on the Azure App Service using Yarn, the same way I do it locally.

I upgraded a few packages yesterday including `react-scripts` and `yarn` itself (2.1.0 and 1.12.1 respectively) and it is now failing with a symlink error:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'D:\local\LocalAppData\Yarn\Cache\v3\npm-loose-envify-1.4.0-71ee51fa7be4caec1a63839f7e682d8132d30caf\node_modules\loose-envify\cli.js' -> 'D:\local\LocalAppData\Yarn\Cache\v3\npm-loose-envify-1.4.0-71ee51fa7be4caec1a63839f7e682d8132d30caf\node_modules\loose-envify.bin\loose-envify'

The strange thing is that `D:\local\LocalAppData\Yarn\Cache\v3\npm-loose-envify-1.4.0-71ee51fa7be4caec1a63839f7e682d8132d30caf\node_modules` is actually empty.

Things that I have tried that didn't work: cleaning Yarn cache, changing the cache dir to a shorter path in case it is reaching path limits, upgrading node to 10.6.0 (latest available on Azure).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I isolated the issue to the interaction between `yarn` and `react-scripts` - `yarn 1.10.0` is the latest that will work with `react-scripts 2.1.0` in this environment.

Edit: the issue was reported and fixed [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6604).

Comment: Seeing the same behavior with just upgrading yarn from 1.10.1 to 1.12.1 - Most likely a change in how Yarn does things.
Another issue with this new Yarn version - an existing shrink-wrap file is no longer causing a warning and ignored - it fails the script.

Comment: For the time being, reverted to yarn 1.10.1 - deployments are working again.

Comment: Yeah, I should open a ticket with them. I really wanna try the .13.x plug n play feature